# how can i read multiple csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

i tried

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Lay4U/a22d415235efcde6c3753867b71a95f3

but it doesn't work

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @GoBackess ! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: hey, did you see my link? i tried utf-8 but it doesn't work

Comment: @GoBackess - So there is no some custom decoding?

Comment: i saved as utf-8 so i don't know why this occur this problem

Comment: i tried ```UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python``` but it doens't work!  is this duplicate qeustion?? i can't understand